# Find a homogeneous linear system for which the space of solutions is exactly the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $v_1, v_2,$ and $v_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ defined by
>   $v_1 = (1,2,10,5), v_2 = (0,1,1,1), v_3 = (1,4,12,7)$ Find a homogeneous linear system for which the space of solutions is exactly the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by
>   $v_1, v_2,$ and $v_3$.

It's related to a previous post feel like this question needed its own post. So basically i need to find $av_1+bv_2+cv_3 = 0$ such that $a=b=c=0$ span a $4$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

---

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1\\2&1&4\\10&1&12\\5&1&7 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$
And reduce it down to 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

which means rank is $2$ because we have $2$ leading ones.

Also i think it's not linearly independent as row 1 $= a+c=0, \text{row} \hspace{.1cm} 2 = b+2c=0, a=-c$ and $b=-2c$

hence $a$,$b$ and $c$ are not equal to zero. Meaning $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly dependent as there are $4$ components to the vectors we are in a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and that subspace is $2$ dimensional as we have to leading ones.

But we need the set to span $\mathbb{R}^4$ in a $4$ dimensional subspace.

Comment: No we don't. It doesn't say "span $\Bbb R^4$". It says "subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ spanned *by* $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$". I.e. the problem is to find a system of equations (expressed in homogenous form) such that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are all solutions, and futher, such that every solution is a linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_3$. For this, it doesn't matter what the dimension of the span of  $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is.

Comment: Homogenous meaning a=b=c=0 hence be linearly independent?

Answer (score 3):

Let $Ax=0$ be a homogeneous linear system with $\text{null}(A)=\text{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.

Then $\text{row}(A)=(\text{null}(A))^{\perp}$, so we can find a basis for $\text{row}(A)$ by reducing

$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&10&5&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\1&4&12&7&0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&2&10&5&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\0&2&2&2&0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&2&10&5&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&8&3&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

If we let $x_3=s$ and $x_4=t$, this gives $x_1=-8s-3t$ and $x_2=-s-t$,

so a basis for $\text{row}(A)$ is given by $r_1=\langle-8,-1,1,0\rangle$ and $r_2=\langle-3,-1,0,1\rangle$.

This gives the homogeneous linear system  $\;\;\;8x_1+x_2-x_3=0$

$\hspace{2.84 in} 3x_1+x_2-x_4=0$.